# Parse from a CSV String instead of a File

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I know that when you want to parse a CSV file you use:

`CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvPath));`

But what about when you have a `String csv;` and you want to parse from that instead?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the same constructor:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader("one,two,three"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) to read from a `String`.